# How can I get rid off this Error Message which cause block any update to OS

Tags: updates

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.01 Since Aug,14 in my laptop; everything has been running fine but this month Jan,15 there is update available called "Ubuntu Base" - after updating that I got this Error Message, Please let me know how to fix this.

The message error is below:

```
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%%5fUS,
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

After this error there is no way I can update the system - please help me how I can get rid of this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve it by running this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```